# Check for size of files deleted after sleep

Tags: bash, awk

I have a script that takes a snapshot of the contents of a directory and then sleeps for a certain amount of time.
After it wakes up, it should accumulate the sum of the size of the files DELETED, not shrunk or grown.

My approach to this was something like this:

```
 FILES_SNAPSHOT="$(ls -l | awk 'NR>1 {print $5,$9}')"
 echo "Sleeping for $1 seconds..."
 sleep $1
 FILES_CURRENT="$(ls -l | awk 'NR>1 {print $5,$9}')"
```

So the snapshot basically stores this:

```
 762 filename.sh
 16 anotherfile.sh
 ...
```

the first column is the size of the file, second name of the file.
after I store this, the script sleeps, and I take another snapshot.
Now, I need to compare the 2nd column of my 2 variables and check for missing filenames, that have been deleted.
After, I need to take these names and match them to the size, using the first var I declared where I still have this information.

I am not quite sure, but I assume these variables just store a regular string that is formatted nicely, now how can I iterate over both strings I store, and know which file is missing? should I use a loop to iterate and then inside the loop should I look for index -1 for missing files?

Or should I use awk somehow, in a combination with merging these variables?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
init:
snap1=$(mktemp)
snap2=$(mktemp)
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%p\t%k\n" | sort > $snap2


loop:
cp $snap2 $snap1
sleep 60
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%p\t%k\n" | sort > $snap2
awk 'BEGIN   {FS="\t"}
     NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
     $1 in a {delete a[$1]} 
     END     {for(k in a) {sum+=a[k]}; print sum+0}' $snap1 $snap2
```

print total size of deleted files in kb.

```
end:
unlink $snap1
unlink $snap2
```

Using `ls` is not recommended in scripts, use `find` instead as shown. Creating files is no concern in Unix systems, you can avoid it if you like to but will just make it harder.   I'm not sure how your script is currently written but the loop content can be replaced with what I suggested. You just need to initialize one of the snapshots and at the end delete both temp files.

Comment: Why does it makes files?
My purpose is to check which files has been deleted from a certain folder within the sleep time, not to create new files.
Thanks for the answer tho.
Also i dont quite understand the code, some of this code is  not working on my linux machine. like comm

Comment: you don't have to but "file" is the basic construct in Unix and its derivatives and the easiest construct to work with.

Comment: Sorry but as a beginner, I don't understand what you mean or how that solves my problem.

Comment: @markp-fuso, right will add the modified files sizes as well, replaced `comm` with `awk` to count just deleted files.